# What is the consequence/disadvantages of continuing to use Windows 7 and not upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, security

Some have recommended me to stay in the latest version of the operating system, but I personally believe that everyone likes this while they continue to receive security updates. Windows 7 will continue to receive until 2020, so should I worry about not upgrading to Windows 10? What consequences/disadvantages can I have?

Comment: from security point of view.. if you are not connected to internet, you are fine. But if you do.. just make sure all of your firewall+antivirus+otherSecurity kit are up to date and avoid visiting dangerous/suspicious website. || "should I worry? " <-- depending on how confident you are on your preventive security action.. If you've done your best.. then it is ok. If security is not a field that you are prepared to invest your effort(or cost?) in.. to get upgraded is better.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thanks for the comment! The truth is that I like this security and I always have my computer as protected as possible, in addition, I have medium/advanced knowledge about viruses and in fact, I am preparing a system to test it intentionally with the strongest viruses for see to what extent my settings are efficient. To navigate I use the browser inside a Sandbox (which isolates any threat from the system) and I have personalized HIPS rules so that any file that comes from the browser and is executable, automatically warns me and blocks it.

Comment: @p._phidot_ It seems complicated, but prevention gives me more security than sometimes a system like Linux that says it is almost impossible to get infected and not use anything to prevent or detect it. I think that excessive trust in an operating system is very bad, and in my case, it does not bother me to have to continue learning to perfect my HIPS rules and security issues.

Comment: glad it helps. ( : || All the best on keeping up your system.. Just make sure to have one Win7 installer handy @ some 5 years later..

Comment: Ask yourself the other question - why wouldn't I upgrade?  I realize you are past the "free" upgrade window so cost may be an issue. What other reasons do you choose to not upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You will not have DirectX 12 support, ever with windows 7.  If you use 3D graphics or play video games you will want it.  DirectX 12 has significant improvements you won't be able to get.  Some of the DirectX 12 features you need software that has DirectX12 support, others are over all improvements.

[image]
Notice DirectX12 is 14 million vs 1.4 million, not really a contest.

One of the biggest features is DirectX 12 is really multi-threaded, and despite claims that DirectX11 is multi-thread, only a tiny fraction(like %1) of it is.  In benchmarks I have had results where DirectX11 multi-threaded is slower than DirectX11 non multi-thread, only by a couple percent but its supposed to be faster.

Yes, Vulkan supports many of these same advancements, but very few games or 3D applications support it.  OpenGL games will not have these advancements either.

It is also worth noting MS Office 2016 and above use DirectX to render graphics.  Also more and more things are getting GPU accelerated one way or another.  Even your web browser uses some DirectX feature to render graphics, at least on a Windows OS.

---

1. No access to the Microsoft Store, although hardly a negative in my opinion.
2. Cortana
3. Dozens if not hundreds of small changes to numerous to mention.
4. Microsoft Edge (future replacement for IE)
5. Microsoft trying hard to get people to login with a windows account instead of a local account.
6. Windows 10 computers can share updates between them instead of having 10 computers download updates from the internet individually.
7. Way more privacy options.
8. Finer controls on what can use devices like web cam,microphone, or etc
9. Automatic patch roll back, if windows doesn't boot at 2-3 tries it will attempt automatic fixes and/or automatically undo patches if any were applied recently.  Saved me several times from a broken computer.
10. HDR High dynamic range, requires a monitor with said support
11. GDI an old single thread primitive graphic engine redone as directx under the hood.  All aspects of GDI, except in api name, have been removed.

Comment: The least worries me are the video games, but it is an interesting contribution for those who do, In fact, I did not know about DirectX 12. In my Notebook I have no problems with that, the times I tried a game to see what performance it had, it worked very well. I guess that's not a problem, in my case. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MarianoM  If and only if your game supported DirectX12, and you had Windows 10, and a 4 core or better CPU then you would see tremendous speed improvements.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware works fine with Windows 7 then there shouldn't be any issue as long as that version is still supported.

However, many or most of the computers you can buy now as new are designed for Windows 10. Those will have issue with Windows 7 or not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

More recent CPU's from Intel won't be supported (officially) on Windows 7. If you don't upgrade your hardware you should be OK.